# Dotfuscated dll in project

Tags: asp.net, obfuscation, dotfuscator

I am using dotfuscator to obfuscate my web application.
I added a Dotfuscator project to my existing project solution and build it.
I got a dll in an encrypted format in the newly added dotfuscator project bin, where the dll in my Project bin remains the same.
Shall I replace the old dll of my project with the new one generated.
If not what is the use of newly generated obfuscated dll.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what you do.

Comment: currently i am adding the obfuscated dll to the published solution and hosted it in iis. But it makes as error.

Comment: What error? Please add that to your answer.